# Combining Two list with Certail Conditions Using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
  List<string> OngoingClass = new List<String>()
   { 
     "FLEXI","RETAIL","LITE","RTSPL"
   };
 List<string> ReturnClass = new List<String>()
  {
     "FLEXI","LITE","RETAIL","RTSPL"
  };
```

Need to Combine those Two List with Certain Conditions.
1 . OngoingClass FLEXI Should Combine with ReturnClass FLEXI - Should not combine with rest of the classes.
2. Same way LITE fare should combine with LITE Fare.
3. Rest of the classes can combine each other.

For Example Result would like

```
{ "FLEXI" , "FLEXI" }
{ "LITE","LITE"}
{ "RETAIL","RETAIL"}
{ "RETAIL","RTSPL"}
{ "RTSPL","RETAIL"}
{ "RTSPL","RETAIL"}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Zip` method.

Comment: what is your aproach? A simple nexted foreach [ OngoingClass.ForEach( oc=> { ...] also ther are better methods

Comment: @Thanks Salas....This is the sample data i have posted here.better to achieve my output in case of  LINQ based solution.

Comment: So the result is a `List<List<string>>`?

Comment: @Tim Thanks,  Yes a kind of ...If needed, I will try to make it better for my output.

Comment: Is the index important? So does it matter if FLEXI is also at the first index of the 2nd list?

Comment: @tim, No ...Flexi might be at different position....it will be any order

Comment: Yes, other than FLEXI and LITE would be cartesian product.

Comment: @VigneshwaranD: i guess your desired result is incorrect. Why you have "RTSPL","RETAIL" twice? The last should be "RTSPL","RTSPL"

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comments, There could be better algorithms to get some combinations, but fo this small dataset this will do the trick

```
    List<Tuple<string, string>> resultSequence = new List<Tuple<string, string>>(); 
    OngoingClass.ForEach( item => 
    {
        ReturnClass.ForEach( item2 => 
            {
                if ((item == item2 && item2 == "FLEXI") || (item == item2 && item2 == "LITE") || ( item != "FLEXI" && item != "LITE" && item2 != "FLEXI" && item2 != "LITE"))
                 { 
                     resultSequence.Add( new Tuple<string, string> ( item, item2 )); 
                  }

            });
    });
```

Show result

```
    foreach (var item in resultSequence)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var OngoingClass = new List<String>() { "FLEXI", "RETAIL", "LITE", "RTSPL" };
var ReturnClass = new List<String>() { "FLEXI", "LITE", "RETAIL", "RTSPL" };

var SpecialClass = new List<String>() { "FLEXI", "LITE" };

var query =
    from o in OngoingClass
    from r in ReturnClass
    where (SpecialClass.Contains(o) && r == o)
        || (!SpecialClass.Contains(o) && !SpecialClass.Contains(r))
    select (o, r);
```

This allows any values to be "special" and only pair with themselves.

I get this result:

[image: query]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that serves the purpose if you don't need/want duplicates. The "special" matches and other matches are aggregated separately, before the results are concatenated into a list of tuples (`List<(string, string)>`).

```
var OngoingClass = new List<String>() { "FLEXI","RETAIL","LITE","RTSPL" };
var ReturnClass = new List<String>() { "FLEXI","LITE","RETAIL","RTSPL" };

var SpecialClass = new List<String> { "FLEXI", "LITE" };

var SpecialResult =
    OngoingClass.Intersect(ReturnClass).Intersect(SpecialClass)
    .Select(special => (special, special));

var OtherResult =
    OngoingClass.Except(SpecialClass)
    .SelectMany(ongoing => ReturnClass.Except(SpecialClass)
        .Select(ret => (ongoing, ret)));

var Result = SpecialResult.Concat(OtherResult).ToList();
```

Result:

```
[0]: ("FLEXI", "FLEXI")
[1]: ("LITE", "LITE")
[2]: ("RETAIL", "RETAIL")
[3]: ("RETAIL", "RTSPL")
[4]: ("RTSPL", "RETAIL")
[5]: ("RTSPL", "RTSPL")
```

Answer (score -2):

Try following :

```
            List<string> OngoingClass = new List<String>() { "FLEXI","LITE","RETAIL","RTSPL"};
            List<string> ReturnClass = new List<String>() { "FLEXI","LITE","RETAIL","RTSPL"}
            var results = OngoingClass.Select((x,i) => new object[] { x, ReturnClass[i]}).ToArray();
```

Comment: Doesnt take into account that OP wants to merge FLEXI and LITE into one "record" but the others as a cartesian product.

Comment: Thanks...But for my Output, FLEXI and LITE should combine with FLEXI and LITE ONLY. Rest of the classes combined with each (RETAIL - RETAIL, RETAIL-RTSPL ,RTSPL-RETAIL, RTSPL-RTSPL)

Comment: @Tim, Exactly...Rest of the classes should be Cartesian Product other than FLEXI and LITE